# Make copy/clone/backup of local git submodule as separate repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I have a git repo "parent" with a git submodule "child". We are going to remove the "child" submodule, but as some developers may have local branches and modifications that aren't pushed to the remote I want them to create a local backup of "child" as a standalone git repo.

I have searched the far reaches of the internet and tried various invocations of simply `cp` and `git clone`, but to no avail.

To backup a normal git repo one can simply copy the entire directory - but this does not work for a git submodule repo as it stores the history and git config in the `.git/` folder of the "parent" repo. I want to clone the repo, keep all local branches and refs and all local changes in the working directory and keep the remote uplink. The "parent" repo should be left unmodified.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A submodule is either "absorbed" or "not absorbed".  (Most should be "absorbed" and that's what you've described.)  For a non-absorbed submodule, what you have is a bog-standard repository, with the `.git` directory/folder containing the repository proper and the rest of that area being the working tree.

An "absorbed" submodule simply has its repository proper *moved*—it's otherwise exactly the same as any repository.  The `.git` you find at the top level of the working tree is a *file* containing the path to the repository proper.  Read the file, use its path to find the repository, and you have the repository.